# Limit date range to datePicker JavaFX 8

Tags: datepicker, javafx-8, date-range

Does anybody know how to set date range limit to a datePicker JavaFX 8?

For example I would like to limit this datePicker only for the actual month (september)

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is to restrict DatePicker for Date Rage from Jan2000 to tillDate.

restrictDatePicker(datePicker, LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 1), LocalDate.now());

We can change the min and max Date value as per requirement.

```
public void restrictDatePicker(DatePicker datePicker, LocalDate minDate, LocalDate maxDate) {
    final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
        @Override
        public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker) {
            return new DateCell() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                     if (item.isBefore(minDate)) {
                        setDisable(true);
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");
                    }else if (item.isAfter(maxDate)) {
                        setDisable(true);
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
    datePicker.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
}
```

Refer link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm#CCHEBIFF

Comment: "Code-only" answers are discouraged on this site; you should explain how this works, as well as how to use it. You should also explain the context: it is not at all obvious here that `checkInDatePicker` is a *different* date picker to the one on which this cell factory is being applied. Finally, since this code was taken from [another site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) you should acknowledge and link that: failure to do so is at the least extremely rude; at worst it could expose you to legal consequences.

Comment: Thank you for your review and suggestion, since this is my first post, i am not clear of all the details to be mentioned. As per your guidance i have updated the answer.

Comment: Doesn't this still allow the user to manually type in out-of-range dates?
What would a solution look like that rejects manual input if it's out of range? Or would it be better (from a UX perspective) to allow invalid values but add a validation message and prevent processing later on?